# Mvc Grid Data Bind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc3.0 razor framework and html Table to bind the data with the help of ViewBag. I have to show Data as per selected option in a dropdownlist.

```
public ActionResult Index(GetFileName fn)
{
....
ViewBag.Grid1Data =dt;
return View();

}
```

At first time, I get the data but next time when another option from dropdown is selected to get second table, the table is not displayed, but I m getting the data.

View includes
dropdown

```
    <select id="Select2">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>des</option>
        <option>fgh</option>
        <option>next</option>
        <option>first</option>
    </select>

// Heading for the table
<h2>@ViewBag.Heads</h2>
   //  Table
 <table id="table" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0" class="TableSty">
                @for (int j = 0; j < ViewBag.Grid1Data.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    var color = "";
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    { color = "#f2f2f2"; }
                    else { color = "white"; }
                    <tr style="background:@color" >
                        @for (int c = 0; c < @ViewBag.Grid1Data.Columns.Count; c++)
                        {
                            <td class="data">@ViewBag.Grid1Data.Rows[j][c].ToString()
                            </td>
                        }

                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

Please help me out to solve the problem

Comment: Can we see your view including any scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Your option list and table is not bound. Best way, you use Html.DropDownListFor to render a dropdown list, so that on every selection from drop down, the page is refreshed and you get the updated data in viewbag.

Or, you have a button to submit and refresh the page manually after you select the DropDown value.